# How to select the options of the caption package correctly? 'Figure' bold, but '(a)' and '(b)' not

Tags: captions, bold

this is my current choice of the options for the caption package:

```
\usepackage[labelfont={rm,md,bf},textfont={rm,md,sl}]{caption}
```

And the results is looking like this:

[image]

I would like to have 'Figure 5.2' with bold font, but '(a)' and '(b)' not. Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\captionsetup[sub]{...}` to change the properties of subcaptions:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
% Configure main captions
\captionsetup     {labelfont={rm,md,bf},textfont={rm,md,sl}}
% Configure subcaptions
\captionsetup[sub]{labelfont={rm,md   },textfont={rm,md,sl}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \caption{bla 1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \caption{bla 2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```